# Check if an email already exists in MysqlDB Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am trying to check if email exsists in my MYSQL table. I am able to successfully connect to the DB and execute SQL queries on the table. But on checking for an email, it gives a SyntaxError on '@' as invalid syntax. I have tried using escape character('\') but it still gives me the same error.

```
import MySQLdb

# Connect
mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                    port=3000,
                     user="root",
                     passwd="xxxxxx",
                     db="xxxxxx")

sqlquery = " select * from <tablename> where email = %s"

mycursor.execute(sqlquery, abc@def.com)

#on using quotes around string
#mycursor.execute(sqlquery, 'abc@def.com')
#TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

#row_count = mycursor.rowcount
#print(row_count)
```

Output

```
(kp_env) storm@storm:/mnt/d$ python abc.py
  File "abc.py", line 40
    mycursor.execute(sqlquery, abc@def.com)
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Also if there is a better way to check if the email exists in the table or not, let me know.

Comment: Do you have a good reason for not using [mysql-connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation.html) ?

Comment: What difference would that make? 
any additional syntax support? @BalajiAmbresh

Comment: It's supported by mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string need doubleqoutoes to be identifies as one string and you need to use a tuple even fpor one parameters

```
import MySQLdb

# Connect
mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                    port=3000,
                     user="root",
                     passwd="xxxxxx",
                     db="xxxxxx")

sqlquery = "select * from <tablename> where email = %s"

mycursor.execute(sqlquery, ("abc@def.com",))
```

I personally prefer `import mysql.connector`

It is newer and makes less problems.

Comment: Works perfectly with MySQLdb. Although my program hangs with mysql.connector